# How to set an ImageDocument to be not dirty in dm-script

Tags: python, image, dm-script, dirty-data

How do I set an `ImageDocument` not to be dirty anymore in python [dm-script](/questions/tagged/dm-script) without saving?

---

I have the python code posted below which can be represented by the following `dm-script` code.

```c
String file_path = GetApplicationDirectory(0, 1).PathConcatenate("test-image.dm4");
Image img := realimage("test", 4, 64, 64);

ImageDocument doc = img.ImageGetOrCreateImageDocument();
doc.ImageDocumentSaveToFile("Gatan Format", file_path);
doc.ImageDocumentShowAtRect(100, 100, 164, 164);
```

The (python code below) creates and shows an `ImageDocument`. The image is saved already. But even saving it directly in *DigitalMicrograph* with its own module it does not recognize that it is saved. I can link the file manually (by executing `dm-script` code from python) but I cannot tell the program that the images are not modified.

There is a function `ImageDocumentIsDirty()`. But this function only returns whether the image is modified or not. I cannot set it.

My program creates a new workspace and loads more than 100 images. When closing *DigitalMicrograph*, it asks for every single of the 100 images if it should be saved. I cannot leave the user with 100 times clicking *No*. Especially because the files are saved.

So, how do I tell [dm-script](/questions/tagged/dm-script) that the image is saved already?

```py
try:
    import DigitalMicrograph as DM
    import numpy as np
    import execdmscript
    import os

    name = "Test image"
    file_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "test-image.dm4")
    
    # create image
    image_data = np.random.random((64, 64))
    image = DM.CreateImage(image_data)
    image.SetName(name)
    
    # create, save and show image document
    image_doc = image.GetOrCreateImageDocument()
    image_doc.SetName(name)
    image_doc.SaveToFile("Gatan Format", file_path)
    print("Saving image to", file_path)
    image_doc.ShowAtRect(100, 100, 164, 164)
    
    # link the image to the file
    dmscript = "\n".join((
        "for(number i = CountImageDocuments() - 1; i >= 0; i--){",
            "ImageDocument img_doc = GetImageDocument(i);",
            "if(img_doc.ImageDocumentGetName() == name){",
                "img_doc.ImageDocumentSetCurrentFile(path);",
                "break;",
            "}",
        "}"
    ))

    svars = {
        "name": image_doc.GetName(),
        "path": file_path
    }

    with execdmscript.exec_dmscript(dmscript, setvars=svars):
        pass
except Exception as e:
    print("{}: ".format(e.__class__.__name__), e)
    import traceback
    traceback.print_exc()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the command you're looking for is
`void ImageDocumentClean( ImageDocument imgDoc )`

as in

```
image img := realimage("test",4,100,100)
img.ShowImage()
imageDocument doc = img.ImageGetOrCreateImageDocument()

Result("\n Dirty? " + doc.ImageDocumentIsDirty())
doc.ImageDocumentClean()
Result("\n Dirty? " + doc.ImageDocumentIsDirty())
```

---

Also: The reason it becomes dirty in a first place is, that window-positions are stored as part of the document. (Other things, like tags, could also apply.)

Comment: This was the exact right answer which works for me. I modified my question so it matches better to this answer. Showing some `dm-script` code may be more understandable for other users.